# container div not centering

Tags: html, css

I imagine you've been asked this 1000 times on here but I have done my homework and I can't seem to get my container div to center for some reason, and I was wondering if you could just help me where I am going wrong please. I have tried a few different ways to align it to the center I will put the codes I have tried below but first I will just confirm the site setup. Container div contains all of the other divs(surprise), but I have set a lot of the divs up with the asbolute value and then positioned them with pixel values, and wondering if this is affecting the container div alignment.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    width:2504px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

body {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    width: 2504px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Without being able to see the divs, it will be nearly impossible for anyone to discern what is the issue in this particular instance.  That being said, I always recommend flexbox:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.  You'll want to use 'display: flex' then 'justify-content: space-around' on the container div.  Then you won't need absolute positioning.

Comment: Currently it is displaying like this:
https://gyazo.com/dac61d89f0638dc05567b3a5c02dbff6

Everything is fine, just it is not centering, i can show the CSS for the divs too if necessary

Comment: I am wondering if it is because I have positioned all of the divs in the container like this for example :
#container #contentbox #navbar {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 50;
 top: 219px;
 left: 330px;
}

Comment: `width: 2504px;`...seriously?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: So should i drop all of the absolute positions and pixel positions and swap them for percentages? I think the reason I used absolute and pixels was because I had issues early on in the website design with percentages for some reason.

Comment: I added an answer that *should* work for you, if I'm looking at the site correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `body > div` where you want to center the latter `div`, something like this should work:

```
body { width: 100%; margin: 0; }
body > div { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 2504px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough if you have already something like that.

```
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>


#container {
width: 2504px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I can see the site, this should work for you:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `position: relative` to the `#container` CSS for the auto margins to function as horizontal centering. And if that `#container` DIV is inside another element, also THAT element needs to be positioned relative or absolute.